# Button to reload UIWebView

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have created a button over top of a UIWebView that I would like to use to refresh the webview when pressed. The following code is in my ViewController class:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let webView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(30, 20, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))
    let button = UIButton(type: .System)

    webView.scalesPageToFit = true
    webView.multipleTouchEnabled = true
    webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com")!))
    self.view.addSubview(webView)

    button.frame = CGRectMake(20, -20, 100, 100)
    button.setTitle("Refresh", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: Selector(reload()), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    webView.insertSubview(button, aboveSubview: webView)
}

func reload() {
    webView.reload()
}
```

I have created the `reload` method to refresh the `webView` but nothing happens when I click the button. I also tried to create the reload method inside viewDidLoad to see if this fixed the issue. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Why do you have a web view outlet and a local variable in view did load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`action: Selector(reload())`

The syntax is wrong. On Xcode version 7.2 and below it should be

`action: Selector("reload")`

on Xcode 7.3 and up it should be

`action: #selector(ClassName.funcName)`

In Xcode 7.2 whole thing should be

```
let webView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(30, 20, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button = UIButton(type: .System)

    webView.scalesPageToFit = true
    webView.multipleTouchEnabled = true
    webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com")!))
    self.view.addSubview(webView)

    button.frame = CGRectMake(20, -20, 100, 100)
    button.setTitle("Refresh", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("reload"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    webView.insertSubview(button, aboveSubview: webView)
}

func reload() {
    webView.reload()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Changing the action call of the button fixed my problem. I am now running into an issue when I remove the webview outlet I get the following error: `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key webView`. Is this because a class name in the storyboard is different?

Comment: @atwalsh04 you can add `webView` from `storyboard` or by code programatically. My code example is adding by code. To fix the issue remove the `webview` view from `storyboard`

Answer (score 3):

You defined webview inside view did load scope, take it out:

```
let webView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(30, 20, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))

func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let button = UIButton(type: .System)

    webView.scalesPageToFit = true
    webView.multipleTouchEnabled = true
    webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com")!))
    webView.layer.zPosition = 1
    self.view.addSubview(webView)

    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
    button.setTitle("Reload Page", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: Selector(reload()), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    webView.insertSubview(button, aboveSubview: webView)
}

func reload() {
    webView.reload()
}
```

Comment: I updated the code in my question to show all code. I tried removing `webView` outside of viewDidLoad, and renamed it to remove conflicts with the @IBOutlet line, but the button still doesn't refresh the page. Any ideas?

Comment: Please put a breakpoint on line "webView.reload()" and see if it reached. Please update.

Comment: The method is called when the app starts up and the breakpoint is reached then, but the breakpoint is not reached when the button is pressed. Could this be caused by the `action: Selector(reload())` part of the button addTarget?